# batch file, for and findstr error

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file

Can anybody explain me, why this code is wrong:

```
set VERSION_FILE_NAME=build_version.h
FOR /F %i in ('findstr /rc:"^\#define _VER_[ABCD] [0-9]" %VERSION_FILE_NAME%') do @echo %%i %%j %%k
```

In console I see "unexpected appearance: build_version.h')."

I try to get strings match the regexp (in future, using delimiters and parse strings)

Comment: It is possible you are looking for `/rc:"^\#define _VER_[ABCD] [0-9]"` regex.

Comment: it's true, but problem in another part of code ... (near %VERSION_FILE_NAME%)

Comment: If using `echo %%i %%j %%k` you also need `for /f "tokens=1-3" %%i in...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say precisely what string you are looking for with the `findstr`, but

```
FOR /F %i in...
```

should be

```
FOR /F %%i in...
```

and the `echo` command must be on the same physical line as the `do` **or** must be constructed as

```
.....do (
 echo....
)
```

where the open-parenthesis is on the same physical line as the `do`.

The `@` is not required normally. as it is standard practice to start a batch file with `@echo off` which turns command-echoing off.

Note that these comments assume you are running a batch file. if you are attempting to run this directly from the prompt, all `%%`s should be reduced to `%`